# How to generate xml file using codename one api?

Tags: java, codenameone

What I need is point 3:

1. Take one xsd file "testField.xsd" and parse it using "com.codename1.xml.XMLParser"
2. alter this xsd file and generate result
3. now I want to save this xsd file with name "testValues.xsd"

What i have done so far :

(1). Take one xsd file "testField.xsd" and parse it using "com.codename1.xml.XMLParser"

> InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(null,
>   "/testField.xsd"+fileName);
>
> Element response = xp.parse(new InputStreamReader(is));

(2). alter this xsd file and generate result

> ```
>  for(FormData fromDataObj : listInputs){
>      response.getElementById(fromDataObj.getInputId()).setAttribute("value",fromDataObj.getInputValue());
>  }
> ```

(3). now I want to save this xsd file with name testValues.xsd

> //want to save above response as "testValues.xsd"

Comment: Could you at least spend the time to ask a real question with proper formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `XmlWriter` class it has the ability to write Element's to XML.

Comment: I have tried this code but gives build error like cannot find symbol FileWriter. code snippet : Writer writer = new FileWriter("test.xsd");XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(false); xmlWriter.writeXML(writer, response);

Comment: There is no FileWriter or java.io.File either. So no sense in that since the filesystem on a mobile device is "different". Use OutputStreamWriter.

Comment: Let me know if I m wrong in this code..it is not generating test.xml file. OutputStream os =  Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("test.xml"); OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os); XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(false);
          xmlWriter.writeXML(writer, response);

Comment: You aren't closing the stream. Are you sure it isn't working? How did you test that?

Comment: Hi Shai.. I have changed my code.FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream("test.xml").write(response.toString().getBytes()); it works fine now. Thanks for help.

Comment: You shouldn't use relative paths in FileSystemStorage. I suggest you readup a bit about the differences between Storage & FileSystemStorage in the developer guide